# how to parse xml file and grab text values

Tags: php, javascript, xml, xml-parsing, fxg

The following is just a snipplet of code from a large fxg file, which is basically just a xml file:

```
<RichText x="14.1655" y="46.5674" columnGap="18" columnCount="1" textAlign="left" fontFamily="Bootstrap" color="#53836A" whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" width="202.712" height="13.334" s7:caps="none" s7:colorName="" s7:colorValue="#B24FA41C" s7:colorspace="cmyk" s7:elementID="line1" s7:fill="true" s7:fillOverprint="false" s7:firstBaselineOffset="ascent" s7:joints="miter" s7:maxFontSize="12" s7:miterLimit="10" s7:referencePoint="inherit" s7:rowCount="1" s7:rowGap="18" s7:rowMajorOrder="true" s7:stroke="false" s7:strokeOverprint="false" s7:warpBend="0.5" s7:warpDirection="horizontal" s7:warpHorizontalDistortion="0" s7:warpStyle="none" s7:warpVerticalDistortion="0" s7:weight="1" ai:aa="2" ATE:C_charRotation="0" ATE:C_horizontalScale="1" ATE:C_kerning="metric" ATE:C_verticalScale="1" ATE:P_autoHyphenate="true" ATE:P_consecutiveHyphenLimit="0" ATE:P_hyphenateCapitalized="true" ATE:P_hyphenatedWordSize="6" ATE:P_hyphenationPreference="0.5" ATE:P_hyphenationZone="36" ATE:P_postHyphenSize="2" ATE:P_preHyphenSize="2" d:userLabel="id:line1">
   <content><p><span>Address Line 1</span></p></content>
</RichText>
```

There are many nodes in the XML file that have a similar structure. But each `RichText` node has a unique element id, `s7:elementID="line1"` in this case.

Using PHP or JavaScript, how can I grab either:

1. the text "Address Line 1"
2. the whole line including content,p,span tags

If I specify the `elementID` I want the content from?

I'm not very familiar with XML so I'm not sure if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load the xml into an object with: `simplexml_load_string()`

then use `->xpath('RichText')` on that object to get the RichText elements.

if you use `->asXML()` on thos elements,

you get `"<content><p><span>Address Line 1</span></p></content>"`

is it always `"<content><p><span>"`?

then you can use `(string) $RichText->content[0]->p[0]->span[0]`

Comment: I think it will always have have the content,p,span tags.

Comment: is there a way to specify exactly the RichText node I want to retrieve the elements from.  There will normally be  5 or 6 RichText nodes in each file.  I need to grab the specific ones based on the elementID of the RichText node.  Is that possible, if I specify the id somehow?

Comment: read more about xpath, think its somthing like ('RichText[id=testid]')

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will look into it more.